# Prevent resize when setting UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have written some auto layout code programmatically. I have successfully achieved the following layout (without an image in the image view):

1. There are two views, an image view followed by a single line label
2. The label is filled with text
3. The image view height and width is constrained to the label's height
4. The label's height is the "intrinsic height"

Everything works perfect.

When I programmatically, in response to some events, set an image in the image view, the image view is resized to fit the image, and this causes the label's height to change to match the image view, ignoring the intrinsic height of the label calculated by the text in the label.

I set the height of the label using this constraint:

```
self.subjectLabel.autoSetContentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis(ALAxis.Vertical);
```

Maybe there is something wrong with that? Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: set `imageView.clipsToBounds=YES;`

Comment: I tried setting clipToBounds = YES but it still has the same behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around this by resizing the UIImage using the ideas from this page: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way.

I resized the image during layoutSubviews to ensure that the frames for all the subviews has been calculated.